# Getting location using wifi only

Tags: android, location

I am developing an android application in which i want to use wifi only to find user's location is it possible to find location of your device just by using Wifi ?
In this app i m trying to guide user to go from one place to another inside a building so i want exact location cell tower location or gps location will not be of any help

Comment: yes it is. Have you tried?

Comment: and you want ignore 3G network location? or GPS?

Comment: Do you want to know if you can get a location using only proximity to various wifi access points,  or do you want to know if you can get a location using say gps with out using mobile data?

Comment: after reading your comments i have edited my question please take a look at my question once again

Answer (score 1):

`LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` will use either Wifi or cell tower location (not GPS).  If you want the best location, that would be fine GPS (wifi is the least accurate.)  You can ask the LocationManager to `getBestProvider` and require fine GPS with:

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

Comment: cell tower location will not be helpfull as i want exact location

Comment: @VarunAjayGupta i don't think that's possible

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest comment, I think you would like to guide a user inside a building and somehow get more accurate locations than a gps location (which would probably not be accurate inside a building anyway).  While there may be some specific situation in which this would be possible, I would say no, there is not a general solution that could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

For Current Location, using GPS is highly recommended. Because with only Wifi, it will not be accurate. But still you can use this:

```
String uriName = "geo:"+ lat+ "," + lon+ "?q=my+street+address";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriName)));
```

This should work with roughly accuracy.

Comment: but gps won't work inside the building nor it would provide pin point locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to guide the user while inside the building, if so, then I don't think that GPS or Wifi will be able to help you.

GPS provides a very fine location but require clear contact with the gps satellites in the space which won't be available inside buildings. Also the accuracy is within some meter distance which won't be effective in your case.

Cellular wifi will provide you location using the nearby cell tower which i think is self explanatory in your case. So, I don't think that both location services will of use in your case.